# PHP mySql data to JSON file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, converters

So, i need to query my database by php and then convert the query into a .json file to use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example?hl=pt-BR).

How can i convert a mysql query through PHP to a .json file somewhat like this:

```
{
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'B', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
         {id: 'C', label: 'C-label', type: 'date'}
        ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: 'a'}, {v: 1.0, f: 'One'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28, 0, 31, 26), f: '2/28/08 12:31 AM'}]},
         {c:[{v: 'b'}, {v: 2.0, f: 'Two'}, {v: new Date(2008, 2, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '3/30/08 12:31 AM'}]},
         {c:[{v: 'c'}, {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'}, {v: new Date(2008, 3, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '4/30/08 12:31 AM'}]}
        ],
  p: {foo: 'hello', bar: 'world!'}
}
```

PS: this example is quoted from google

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` function.

1. Fetch data from db and assign it to an array
2. Then use `json_encode($result_array)`. This will produce the json result. [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
3. Use `file_put_contents` function to save the json result to your .json file

Following is an example code,

```
$result = mysql_query(your sql here);    
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Generate the output in desired format
    $data = array(
        'cols' => ....
        'rows' => ....
        'p' => ...
    );
}

$json_data = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('your_json_file.json', $json_data);
```

Comment: exactly.get the result from json_encode($array) and send it to a .json file so i can get it later to output in a google chart

Answer (score 1):

convert mysql table to php object using [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) and then to json with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

mysql_fetch_object fetches row. so use loop to construct a table object.

code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
$table=array();
while($row=$mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  $table.push($row);
  unset($row);
}
echo json_encode($table);
```