# How to build my JSON data with only one MySQL request?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is it possible to get a JSON output looks like with one query?

```
[{
    "name": "Date",
    "data": ["2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", "2013-05-01"] //data from grouped from_date column
}, {
    "name": "KD",
    "data": [4, 5, 6, 2, 5] // arrays from saldo_sprzedazy for KD sales_group
}, {
    "name": "SG",
    "data": [5, 2, 3, 6, 7] // arrays from saldo_sprzedazy for SG sales_group
}]
```

My current query:

```
SELECT
    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy),
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group,
    klienci_ax_all.nazwa
FROM
    sales_raport_all
INNER JOIN
    klienci_ax_all
ON
    sales_raport_all.konto=klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
WHERE
    YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY
    sales_raport_all.from_date
```

I group by from_date but I need to also group by sales_group...
Is it possible to do this on the mysql table with I have?
i try to prepare data to Column Highcharts [highcharts.com/demo/column-basic](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic)

**EDIT:**

OK, maybe this will clarify my earlier question :)
This is my PHP code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    sales_raport_all.to_date,
    sales_raport_all.konto,
    SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy),
    SUM(sales_raport_all.wartosc_kosztowa),
    SUM(sales_raport_all.marza),
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group,
    klienci_ax_all.nazwa
FROM
    sales_raport_all
INNER JOIN
    klienci_ax_all
ON
    sales_raport_all.konto=klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
WHERE
    YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY
    sales_raport_all.from_date");


$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Data';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['from_date'];  
}

$querySG = mysql_query("SELECT
    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    sales_raport_all.to_date,
    sales_raport_all.konto,
    SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy),
    SUM(sales_raport_all.wartosc_kosztowa),
    SUM(sales_raport_all.marza),
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group,
    klienci_ax_all.nazwa
FROM
    sales_raport_all
INNER JOIN
    klienci_ax_all
ON
    sales_raport_all.konto=klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
WHERE
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group = 'SG'
AND
    YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY
    sales_raport_all.from_date");
$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'SG';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($querySG)) {
    $series1['data'][] = intval($r['SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy)']);
}
....
```

My question is: do I have to write a separate query for every specific sales_group or is there a simpler way?

Now I use json like this:

```
$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);
array_push($result,$series3);

print json_encode($result);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mySql data to JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317519/php-mysql-data-to-json-file)

Comment: Why build it yourself. Just use your php associative arrays then use json_encode to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: ok, look at this example of mysql table [stacked_table.png](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/stacked_table.png). i dont know how to prepare my data because i dont have column named sales_group but i have it in row... if i use two or more loop in while... but it is fast for more than 1mln data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in one go, you have to group by both `sales_group` and `from_date`:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    sales_raport_all.to_date,
    sales_raport_all.konto,
    SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy),
    SUM(sales_raport_all.wartosc_kosztowa),
    SUM(sales_raport_all.marza),
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group,
    klienci_ax_all.nazwa
FROM
    sales_raport_all
INNER JOIN
    klienci_ax_all
ON
    sales_raport_all.konto=klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
WHERE
    YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY
    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group
ORDER BY
    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group");
```

Then collect all the possible dates and all the data in a raw array.

```
$raw = array();
$dates = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $date = $r['from_date'];
    if (!in_array($date, $dates)) $dates[] = $date;
    $sales_group = $r['sales_group'];
    $raw[$sales_group][$date] = intval($r['SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy)']);
}
```

Lastly go through the raw data, and check if on a given date the sales_group has relevant data or set it to zero.

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = array('name' => "Date", 'data' => $dates);
foreach ($raw as $name => $d) {
    $new_data = array('name' => $name, 'data' => array());
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $new_data['data'][] = isset($d[$date]) ? $d[$date] : 0;
    }
    $data[] = $new_data;
}
```

The final `$data` will have the desired structure and all the data you need.

Comment: i almost understand... but when i try to print print json_encode($data); is empty(null) [http://pastebin.com/Ynmp72v5](http://pastebin.com/Ynmp72v5)

Comment: That can happen if any of your sales group names have non Unicode characters in them. You have to escape those with htmlentities() or change the encoding to Unicode. Try to dump $data with var_dump() to check what's inside. Also there is json_last_error() to check what's the problem with the encoding.

Comment: I check with var_dump($data) and i have results : array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Date" ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL } } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(452) } } } But this dont tell me to much :(

Comment: i also put my sql if you would look: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/186751/2)

Comment: Oh, I think I have the problem, the date it not `$r['sales_raport_all.from_date']` but `$r['from_date']`. Should work that way.

Comment: There are still missing grouping by sales_group - might because foreach does not have a sales_group?

Comment: OMG, sorry, yes `$r['sales_group']` instead of `$r['klienci_ax_all.sales_group']`, now it should work.

Comment: now its really ok. I don't saw that also.Thanks for help. I really appreciate it.